# Increasing the animation speed of indeterminate QProgressBar

Tags: qt, c++11

On windows, setting an indeterminate QProgressBar with range in (0, 0) leads to an animation of a green horizontal gradient moving from left to right. However, I would like to increase the speed of the animation. How can this be achieved?